# How to join multiple tables using linq with group by condition

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to fetch the list of employer with inner list details to show multiple address. I have tried the following code and can able to fetch the EmpConnectionNumber, EmpState. I could able to fetch the StoreID, StoreStaffName, Address,                              ContactNumber details from store  and StoreStaffList  tables.

```
        List<Model.ListEmployer.Employer> employer_list = null;
        employer_List = (from a in Employer
                         join b in store on a.EmployerID equals b.EmployerID
                         join c in StoreAddress on b.StoreID equals c.StoreID
                         join d in StoreStaffList on c.storeAddressID equals d.StoreAddressID
                         where a.EmployerType == "Contract" 
                         group new { a, c } by new { a.ConnectionNumber, c.state } 
                         into grp 
                         select new Model.ListEmployer.Employer
                         {
                             EmpConnectionNumber = grp.Key.ConnectionNumber,
                             EmpState = grp.Key.State,
                             AddressHistory = new List<Model.list Employer.AddressHistory>
                            {
                                new Model.ListEmployer.AddressHistory
                                {
                                    StoreID = b.StoreID,
                                    StoreStaffName = d.StoreStaffName,
                                    Address = d.Address,
                                    ContactNumber = d.ContactNumber
                                }
                            }
                         }). ToList();
```

Can anyone help on this solution to get it done.

my intension is to show multiple address details inside the same Employer list itself

Comment: Do you have navigation properties between these entities?

Comment: Yes I have the navigation property.

Comment: Should really need to write `join` then..

Comment: It's a bit weird that your store address has many store staff list though.. what does it mean for the list of staff a store has to be related to the address? And how often does a store change address? Is "store" like "chain" and "storeaddress" like "branch"?

Comment: I mean I want to fetch the employer list history here. Not the company address

Comment: Does the code written do what you want? Are you trying to add to it? Or fix something about it?